# Update child's state properly in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I figured out that my state is not being updated correctly. If you see the code below `console.log(this.props.clickedImage)` is giving the value that I expect, but `console.log(this.state.items);` is not.

I'm using `componentWillReceiveProps()` to update it but I'm not sure that this is the good way to go. What's the best way to do this?

The parent:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // set the state to handle which of the panes displays the information you want
    this.handleChildClick = this.handleChildClick.bind(this),
    this.state= {
        clickedItem: 'none',
    };
}

handleChildClick(src) {
    this.setState({ clickedItem: src });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="ao">
                <CharacterForm clickedImage={this.state.clickedItem}/>
                <SearchForm image_clicked={this.handleChildClick}/>

        </div>

    );
}
```

Child A:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [
                { name: "one", divStyle: this.props.clickedImage},
                { name: "two", divStyle: this.props.clickedImage},
                { name: "three", divStyle: this.props.clickedImage},
            ]
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.itemsLeft !==this.props.clickedImage){
            this.setState({

            })
        }
    }


    render() {
        console.log(this.props.clickedImage); 
        console.log(this.state.items);

        return this.state.itemsRight.map(item => (
            <FrameCharacter key={item.name} item={item} />
        ));
    }
```

Child B:

```
render() {
    <img src="../images/misc/eq.png" onClick={() => image_clicked(eq.image)}/>
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your complete code so that community can understand the question better

Comment: I edited my initial post, sorry

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated. This case is the exact reason why `getDerivedStateFromProps` hook was introduced. It allows to derive state from props, including ones that were initially received in constructor:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  return {
    items: [
      { name: "one", divStyle: props.clickedImage }
      ...
    ];
  }
}
```

Notice that `props` are next props in `getDerivedStateFromProps`. In case it's necessary to access previous `clickedImage` prop to fully replace `componentWillReceiveProps`, `clickedImage` can be stored to the state as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When does this function is getting called? I try to log the value of props and state but no results

Comment: It's called every time the component is updated, including initial render. See http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/ . Notice that it's `static` and requires 16.4 or higher. If it still doesn't work for you, consider providing a demo that shows the problem.

Comment: This is working, just because of typo. The diagram you gave is also interesting, thanks for sharing